# How can i test response for an API call in a callback function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jasmine

I want to test a async API which accepts 2 parameters. First is a string of operation to be performed and second is callback function. I want to test the response which i get as a parameter in the callback function.

```
someApi('getName', (response) => {
  // I want to test the response object.
  console.log(response);
})
```

I can test the API call like :

```
spyOn(window.someApi)
expect(someApi).toHaveBeenCalledWith('name_1', jasmine.any(Function))
//let mockResponse = {name:'name1'};
```

But how do i test if i am getting correct response as response.name = 'name1'.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
someApi('getName', (response) => {
// I want to test the response object.
   if(response.name === 'name you want to match') {
      //do something if it matches
   }
    else {
     //do something if it doesn't match
    }
})
```

Comment: I want to test it using Jasmine, in test cases. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It can be done something like:

```
const lastCall = someApi.calls.mostRecent();
const callback = lastCall.args[1];
callback({name:'name1'})
expect(someVariableWhichUsesThisResponse).toBe({name:'name1'})
```